# Replace innerHTML in plain JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove everything except the img-element from the footer container:

```
<footer>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <img src="logo.jpg">
</footer>
```

In JQuery I would do this:

```
var logo = $('footer img');
$('footer').html(logo);
```

How do I do that in plain JS?

Comment: try using getElementByTagName....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without recreating the original element, if you want

```
var footer = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];
var img = footer.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
footer.innerHTML = '';
footer.appendChild(img)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dsnftpoz/)

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
  document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0].innerHTML =  
            document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]
```

Comment: Is the innerHTML on the img element correct? I would assume you'd want the whole element and not only its contents.

Answer (score 1):

That's not valid, you're setting the `html` of the footer to be the  `logo` jQuery object? I think you mean the logo HTML.

You would do:

```
var footer = document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0];
var logo = footer.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

footer.innerHTML = logo.outerHTML;
```

Comment: @user3848987 Yep you're right, should be `outerHTML` I've fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the querySelector() function.
It is exactly the same as jquery's selector function.

```
var logo = document.querySelector("footer img");
var footer = document.querySelector('footer');
footer.innerHTML = "";
footer.appendChild(logo);
```

More information about querySelector in [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp).

Comment: but I guess querySelector is slower then getElementsByTagName, isn't it?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector-vs-queryselector-by-id

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too:

```
var footer = document.querySelector("footer");
var replecedElement = document.querySelector("footer img");
footer.innerHTML = "";
footer.appendChild(replecedElement);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t1qwn6bt/